# Missing class com.google.errorprone.annotations.Immutable on building release apk with R8

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8, tink

I am getting below error on building the release apk with R8 enabled:

```
Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in C:\\Users\\y509118\\AndroidStudioProjects\\SafeBox\\app\\build\\outputs\\mapping\\release\\missing_rules.txt.\n","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class com.google.errorprone.annotations.Immutable (referenced from: com.google.crypto.tink.KeyTemplate and 4 other contexts)","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in C:\Users\y509118\AndroidStudioProjects\SafeBox\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.


Missing class com.google.errorprone.annotations.Immutable (referenced from: com.google.crypto.tink.KeyTemplate and 4 other contexts)
```

content of above mentioned missing_rules file:

```
# Please add these rules to your existing keep rules in order to suppress warnings.
# This is generated automatically by the Android Gradle plugin.-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.Immutable
```

should I add `-dontwarn` in pro-guard rules and or add some `-keep` rule?

Comment: use -dontwarn, issue is reported here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195752905

Answer (score 0):

this error is caused by a **missing class**. please use as following in your **app level**
**build.gradle** to get rid of this error:-

> //https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.errorprone/error_prone_annotations

```
implementation 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.23.0'
```

and sync with gradle. thanks for asking such questions and make SO community better.